# Why does the line below the lock wait get executed though wait has been specified?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, wait, notify

I have written the following code where the start method is supposed to wait until the stop method notifies it. But during the execution the log line below the start method gets printed though I have specified it to wait. Below shown is my start method implementation is as follows.

```
private static boolean stopThread = false;

public static void start(String[] args) {
    startThread();
    synchronized (serviceThread) {
        try {
            while(stopThread) {
            serviceThread.wait();
            }
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Thread: Just after wait method");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "'Wait' interrupted: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Below shown is my stop method implementation.

```
public static void stop(String[] args) {

    if (serviceThread != null) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Stopping the thread");
        serviceThread.interrupt();
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Thread: Successfully interrupted");
        synchronized (serviceThread) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "About to notify");
            serviceThread.notify();
            stopThread = true;
        }
        stopPlugins();
        kubeLogManager.closeLogger();
        messageBus.terminateMessageBus();
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "No thread to interrupt");
    }
}
```

Why does that log line below the wait method get printed even before the stop method has been called? Please advice.

Comment: Should say `while (!stopThread)`, not `while(stopThread)`

Comment: Shouldn't I wait till stop Thread becomes true? Because it has been declared to be false?

Comment: Yes... `while(!stopThread)` will loop until it becomes true

Comment: That was sloppy! :D Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for Object.wait:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()

> interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop:
>
> ```
>  synchronized (obj) {
>      while (<condition does not hold>)
>          obj.wait();
>      ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
>  }
> ```

You should use a variable to indicate when `stop()` has been called, and set it before you call `notify()`.  Also, it's safer to use `notifyAll()`, since it still works if you somehow get another thread waiting on the object.

Comment: In the fist example this link, http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/ it does wait without any loop or condition variables? We should be able to do that right? Else we wouldn't need wait-notify? Please advice.

Comment: Nope, the example over there is just wrong.  But if you just want to wait until the thread is done then you can use Thread.join()

Comment: Just one more doubt before we wrap this up. I have used the lock on the thread I had created. What would be the difference if I put the lock on the object of this class? Because in this application, the main method is started in one thread and rest of the execution is executed on another thread.

Comment: Note: if you're going to use Thread.join, then don't synchronize().  Also notice that the documentation for Thread.join(0) suggest that you shouldn't .wait on Thread instances

Comment: Hey can you also please advice on the last comment I have posted asking the question above?

Comment: It's best to make a `new Object()` just to use as a monitor.  That way you can be sure that nobody else is sychronizing on it, waiting on it, or notifying on it, because nobody else can see it.  Otherwise using `this` is also quite common